# Can I get some clarity on the definition of a bounded operator?

Tags: operator-theory

I'm trying to ensure I understand the definition of a bounded operator. Is it essentially stating that for some vector x in the vector space X, if  you apply the operator to x and it's less than or equal to the original vector in x, multiplied by some constant, then the operator is bounded? I added a picture with the definition below.

[image: Bounded Operator Definition]

Comment: The reason this is a useful definition is: for a **linear** operator $L$, we have: $L$ is continuous if and only if $L$ is bounded.  And the "bounded" definition is easier to check than the "continuous"definition.

Comment: $\forall$ means "for all", not "for some" (which you have in your question) - is that part of what is confusing you?

Answer (score 1):

More carefully, taking the length of $L(x)$ results in at most some constant $C$ times the length of $x$ itself, where the constant $C$ is the same for all possible $x$.

Conceptually, you want to allow large $L(x)$ only if $x$ is large.